# Checking output of a shell command in ansible

Tags: bash, shell, ansible

I'm trying to write an Ansible script that runs a shell pipeline, and determines whether to terminate the playbook's execution based on that pipeline's output.

Here is the problematic code:

```
  - name: Check if the number of HITACHI devices is equal to 1
    shell: lsscsi | grep HITACHI | awk '{print $6}' | wc -l
    register: numOfDevices
    when: numOfDevices|int  == 1
```

Here is the error:

```
{  
   "failed":true,
   "msg":"The conditional check 'numOfDevices|int  == 1' failed.  
The error was: error while evaluating conditional (numOfDevices|int  == 1): 'numOfDevices' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/config/test.yml': line 14, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Check if the number of HITACHI devices is equal to 1\n    ^ here\n"
}
```

Can someone tells me what could be the issue?

Comment: `grep | awk | wc`? You realize `awk` could do the job of all three commands?

Comment: BTW, what's your actual goal here? Do you want to stop playbook execution if there isn't exactly one Hitachi device? Run some other command if there is (or isn't) exactly one Hitachi device? Something else? The `when` clause doesn't make sense where you have it; the question is where it *should* be.

Comment: I want to stop the playbook if there isn't exactly one Hitachi device.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification -- that lets me simplify my answer significantly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider doing the comparison in your shell command:

```
  - name: Check if the number of HITACHI devices is equal to 1
    shell: test "$(lsscsi | awk '/HITACHI/ { count++ } END { print count }')" -eq 1
```

You don't need to use `register` at all here, since the default `failedWhen` is when the exit status of a command is nonzero.

---

If you **did** want to use `register`, however:

```
  - name: Check if the number of HITACHI devices is equal to 1
    shell: lsscsi | awk '/HITACHI/ { count++ } END { print count }'
    register: countHitachiDevices
    failed_when: int(countHitachiDevices.stdout) != 1
```

Note the use of `failed_when` instead of `when`: A `when` clause determines if a command is going to be run at all, whereas a `failed_when` clause determines whether that command is determined to have failed.

Comment: Can you explain what is the `-eq 1` for?

Comment: `[` in shell is the command also called `test`; http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html documents the POSIX baseline functionality all implementations are guaranteed to have. `-eq` is numeric comparison.

Comment: Thanks! The first solution worked great. When i tried to run the seconds solution i get: `fatal: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'int(countHitachiDevices.stdout) != 1' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (int(countHitachiDevices.stdout) != 1): 'int' is undefined"}`. Do you know why?

Comment: Nope, I'd need to repro.

Comment: @Omri Try `countHitatchiDevices.stdout|int`